# Store pointer to array in file scope from array paramter in a function

Tags: c, misra

I am rebuilding an application to comply with MISRA-rules and using QA-C to analyze my code.

One of those annoying rules involve pointers and arrays.
You can't say:

```
char foo[10];
char * bar = &(foo[0]);

bar[5] = 'a';
```

Nor can you then do:

```
*bar = 'a';
bar++;
```

My problem involves two functions and a file-scope variable.

Originally this code did the following (bit-pseudocode-like):

```
static char * bufferPtr;

static void foo_a(char * buffer /* other params */)
{
    bufferPtr = buffer;

    /* some logic goes here */
    switch()
    {
        case 'b':
           foo_b(/* some param */);
}

static void foo_b(/* parameters */)
{
    if (/*something*/)
    {
        /*  some logic */
        foo_c(/* data-param */);
        /* some logic */
    }
    else
    {
        /*  some logic */
        foo_c(/* data-param */);
        /* some logic */
    }
}

static void foo_c(char data)
{
    *buffer++ = data;
}
```

I've tried to rewrite it to the following:

```
static char (*bufferPtr)[];
static char bufferIndex;

static void foo_a(char buffer[] /* other params */)
{
    bufferPtr = &buffer;
    bufferIndex = 0;

    /* same */
}

static void foo_b(/* parameters */)
{
    /* same */
}

static void foo_c(char data)
{
    (*bufferPtr)[bufferIndex] = data;
    bufferIndex++;
}
```

But then both misra and my compiler (softune, by Fujitsu) complain.
Compiler says:

> assignment incompatible pointer types from `CHAR **' to`CHAR (*)[]': operator `='

Misra says:

> [C] Right operand of assignment is not of compatible pointer type.
>   Address of automatic object exported to a pointer with linkage or wider scope.

However I do need to be able to index an array in the foo_c function. Or are there other ways to and follow misra and make my code work.

If I do the following in the same file:

```
static CHAR foo[10];
static CHAR (*bar)[];
static void f(void)
{
    bar = &foo;
}
```

Then nor Misra nor my compiler complain about anything.

Comment: It's this line it doesn't like: bufferPtr = &buffer; so can you not static char **bufferPtr; ?

Comment: @SpacedMonkey sadly not possible because you can't/shouldnd subscript pointers as if they are arrays.

Comment: In VS2010, buffer is a char * inside foo_a() so there is no solution that I can see.  You'll have to find a bit of MISRA compliant code that already does this.

Comment: @DaanTimmer You can do that, that's one of the intended uses of pointers. Does MISRA say you shouldn't?

Comment: @SpacedMonkey Not only in VS2010, as function arguments, arrays decay into pointers to the first element. That's part of the spec.

Comment: @DanielFischer but this is valid: `void foo(char buf[]){buf[i] = 'f';i++;}` while this isn't: `void foo(char * buf){buf[i] = 'f'; i++}` nor: `void foo(char * buf){*buf = 'f'; buf++;}`

Comment: Who says the first is valid, but the second isn't? They are **exactly** the same.

Comment: why `void foo(char * buf){*buf = 'f'; buf++;} ` is invalid?

Comment: Misra rule 17.4 says that. It sadly is not something that I made up. Here is a discussion about it: http://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=641

Comment: No it does not. `char * buf` is not an array type and `*buf = 'f'` is not applying indexing.

Comment: @Agent_L but `buf++;` is pointer arithmetic. Which is not allowed according to rule 17.4

Comment: I was thinking it was MISRA. The more I learn about their rules, the less sense they make. As stated, the first two are exactly the same.

Comment: @DaanTimmer How can we comply to rule 17.4 if we don't know the it?
I'm sorry, you have to go to someone with access to rules to get more help.

Comment: @DanielFischer same problem here. :-) But rules are rules. I guess I'll just change the flow of functionality where I keep passing the buffer-array to each subsequent function. Because A) it is safe, B) compiler doesn't complain C) misra doesn't complain. Though it is a ugly workaround.

Comment: @DanielFischer Looks like they're designed to keep sloppy programmers in check. This can be good when designing from scratch, but seems that adapting existing software is a nightmare at best.

Comment: @Agent_L we are rewriting 95% of the code. But in this case it was a/the source of esp_printf: http://fizzy.biz/~phillip/programming_notes/embedded_c/esp_printf.c.html We had to modify this to comply with misra. We can't use vsprintf from stdio.h because misra complains about using stdio.h due to undefined behavior and should be avoided in production code...

Comment: @DaanTimmer On the other hand, global variables are considered bad by many too, so explicitly passing the buffer array also has its upsides. (And yes, if you have to comply, you have to, but it'd be nice if the rules made sense.)

Comment: @DanielFischer but it wasn't global. It was in file-scope and not global-scope. Guess I'll just answer my own question with 'this' solution and leave it was is. The whole file is compliant now..

Comment: @DaanTimmer - it's still global and not reentrant. It doesn't matter what namespace or scope it hides behind. Just like class static members are also no different than globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the flow of this code to just pass the buffer parameter to each subsequent version.

It is ugly, but it works and is somewhat safe. 'according to misra'

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense to me:

```
static char (*bufferPtr)[];
static char bufferIndex;
```

I'd make it like that:

```
static char *bufferPtr_new;
static int bufferIndex_new;
```

And replace every *bufferPtr with bufferPtr_new[bufferIndex_new]
But perhaps explain to us what's wrong with current code, according to MISRA.

Comment: According to misra you can't use a pointer as if it is an array: `static char *ptr;` `static char index;` `ptr[index] = 'f';` results in: An array subscript operator is being used to subscript an expression which is not of array type. This is perfectly legitimate in the C language providing the pointer addresses an array element; but may be discouraged in some coding standards which seek to restrict the use of pointers.

Comment: @DaanTimmer so write `*(ptr + i)` instead of `ptr[i]`. Does that satisfy MISRA?

Comment: @DanielFischer, hah, I was going to say that, but the old code never used indexing...

Comment: @DanielFischer pointer arithmetric should be avoided. `ptr + i` is that kind of airthmetric that should be avoided. (If possible. currently we are trying to remove all of it). Unless there is no real solution)

Comment: @Agent_L The example before the code did, together with the comment here, I surmised the actual indexing was removed during the extraction of the code for the question.

Comment: @DaanTimmer [insert strong language of choice] `*(ptr + i)` is, per the standard, exactly equivalent to `ptr[i]`. Using one, but condemning the other is ridiculous. The only concern is that only reasonable values of `i` are used, but that concerns all forms of access.

Comment: @DaanTimmer pointer arithmetic is perfectly legitimate construct, while indexing something that's not an array is language abuse (and arithmetic is still done). Yet, you're trying to replace the former with the latter to fulfill requirements that say exactly otherwise.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oke, but imagine the following. The array is changed from 8-bit wide to 16-bit wide. But we are still incrementing i with +1. You'll get an alignment error when using *(ptr+i) but not using ptr[i].

Comment: @Agent_L the original source is also an array and not a pointer.

Comment: @DaanTimmer The increment is in units of `sizeof *ptr`, not in bytes or octets. If you have `uint32_t *ptr;`, then `(char*)(ptr + 1) == ((char*)ptr) + 4` if `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: @DaanTimmer No, even if you change from chars to 49-byte structs, ptr+1 still means "one object".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're going to like this:

```
static char *(bufferPtr[10]); /* must have a size */
static char bufferIndex;

static void foo_a(char buffer[])
{
    *bufferPtr = buffer;
    bufferIndex = 0;
    /* etc */ 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is the same as `static char * bufferPtr[10]` which is an array of pointers and not a pointer to array

Answer (score 0):

```
static void foo_a(char * buffer /* other params */)
```

The argument `buffer` is a pointer, not an array, so trying to treat it as an array elsewhere is going to fail.

The sensible thing would be to have `foo_a` accept a pointer to an array (`char (*buffer)[N]` for some N) or a pointer to a `struct` containing an appropriate sized array.  You can then assign to a file static `char (*bufferPtr)[N]` or (better) pass the array pointer through your call chain.

Comment: I've also tried that. but then it was complaining elsewhere that it was converting char (*)[] to char **. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @DaanTimmer well, fix the code that does that conversion then.

Answer (score 0):

> One of those annoying rules involve pointers and arrays. You can't say: ....

```
char foo[10];
```

Perfectly fine, except for the char type which isn't allowed.

```
char * bar = &(foo[0]);
```

Fine if foo is declared with array syntax. If foo was declared using pointer syntax it violates rule 17.4. See the fix for rule 17.4 further below.
Also, the parenthesis doesn't make any sense whatsoever, neither for MISRA nor for other reasons.

```
bar[5] = 'a';
```

Perfectly fine.

```
*bar = 'a';
```

Perfectly fine.

```
bar++;
```

This isn't allowed by rule 17.4, which is stating that array indexing is the only allowed form of pointer arithmetic. It is indeed a very dumb rule and I believe it will be removed in the next version of MISRA. I actually once addressed this rule with the committee and they couldn't give any rationale for the rule other than cosmetics.

The solution is to create a deviation from MISRA-C for this rule, that's what most MISRA-implementations seem to do. Don't just blindly follow MISRA. 90% of the rules are good, but there are some odd ones lacking a rationale.